# PageHeaderSection of Telerik Reporting

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

Is it possible to split a PageHeaderSection into two columns in Telerik Reporting? If so, then how?

This is my code:

```
this.HeaderSection = new Telerik.Reporting.PageHeaderSection();
```

Comment: I think that teleriks forum might be a better help on such a specific library (http://www.telerik.com/forums), and this demo might help: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/columns-rows/columns/multi-column-headers/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add  two **Text Boxes or Panal** in the header section and put your items in that this will  split your Header into  two  parts . 
hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Milind Satpute](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4613540/milind-satpute) you should set docking info of the two textboxes or panels for right exporting
(for example you can set as right-left or top-bottom)